# Save just the second element of each line from a file into a vector in c

Tags: c, arrays, file, vector

I have this function that saves in an integer variable all the numbers from a text file. But I want to make a change so that I can save just the second number in each line into a vector and then print the whole vector. Here is an example of the `file.txt`:

```
123  19
321  18
432  9
876  16
875  17
```

And here is the code that must be changed:

```
void LerVetor(int *V, int *N)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int marks;
    fp = fopen("dados3.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Falha ao abrir ficheiro\n");

    rewind(fp);

    do
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &marks);
        printf("%d\n", marks);

    } while (!feof(fp));

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The output is the same as the `file.txt` because the code just prints the content of the file.

Resume: Save just the second numbers of each line, ex: `19`, `18`, `9`..., in a vector and then print the vector.

Comment: regarding: `rewind(fp);`  the file was just opened, so the 'file pointer' will already be at the beginning of the file,  so this statement is not needed

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Falha ao abrir ficheiro\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a c library function, should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using: `perror( "fopen failed" ); as that will output both the error message and the text reason to `stderr`.

Comment: Please read: [while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: OT: regarding: `fscanf(fp, "%d", &marks);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers.  In the current scenario any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: So what are `int *V` and `int *N` for?

Comment: If you want the second number you can just use two format specifiers, i.e. scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) and ignore the result in a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is to pass a pointer to the vector (array of ints) where you need to store the values as a parameter of the function.

To dispose the first value in every line you can use a discard specifier `%*d`:

**[Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hM17sYgin3nWbqER)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void LerVetor(int* vector)
{
    FILE *fp; 

    if (!(fp = fopen("dados3.txt", "r"))){
        perror("Falha ao abrir ficheiro");        //print eventual open file error
        return;
    }

    // keep reading lines discarding first value with %*d avoiding container overflow
    for(int i = 0; fscanf(fp, "%*d %d", &vector[i]) == 1 && i < 100; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", vector[i]);                //printing vector values

    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void)
{
    int vector[100];
    LerVetor(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a nice day! =D

Comment: You are welcome @HenriqueJesus, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. groups the variables with where they are used
3. properly checks and handles I/O errors
4. read/displays the second number from each line of the file
5. performs the desired functionality

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void LerVetor( void ) 
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("dados3.txt", "r");
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror("fopen to read: dados3.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int marks;        
    int dummy;
    while( fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &dummy, &marks) == 2 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", marks);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```